# Find an equation of a plane which is tangent to the graph of the paraboloid $z=x^2+4y^2+1$ and contains the origin (0, 0, 0).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find an equation of a plane which is tangent to the graph of the paraboloid $z=x^2+4y^2+1$ and contains the origin (0, 0, 0).

I was able to get the partial derivative and came up with the following formula of the plane:
$2x_0(x-x_0)+8y_0(y-y_0)-z(z-z_0)=0$

However, how do I find $(x_0, y_0)$, the point where the plane is tangent to the paraboloid?

Comment: *Hint*: Is the origin on the paraboloid?

Comment: There was a typo with the equation, just fixed it.

Comment: Your formula for the plane is incorrect (having a $z^2$ term).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replies by @WindSoul and @Gaurang provide the answer to your question, but I feel like the essence is lost a bit. This reply summarises it as concisely as possible.

The equation of the tangent plane is:
$$ z-z_0 = 2x_0 (x-x_0) + 8y_0 (y-y_0)$$
Since $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ must lie on the paraboloid, we have:
$$ 2x_0^2 + 8y_0^2 = z_0 = x_0^2 + 4y_0^2 + 1 $$
$$ x_0^2 + 4y_0^2 = 1 \tag{1}$$
Since $(0,0,0)$ must lie on the tangent plane, we have:
$$ 0-z_0 = 2x_0 (0-x_0) + 8y_0 (0-y) $$
$$ z_0 = 2x_0^2 + 8y_0^2 = 2(x_0^2 + 4y_0^2)\tag{2}$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain $z_0=2$. You can freely choose $x_0$ and $y_0$, as long as $(1)$ holds. Examples are: $(1,0)$, $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(2^{-1/2},2^{-3/2})$. In general, we can find $x_0$ and $y_0$ in terms of a parameter $\theta$:
$$\begin{cases}
    x_0 = \cos(\theta) \\
    y_0 = \frac{1}{2} \sin(\theta)
\end{cases}$$
Choose any $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and you will find a valid point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ where the plane touches the paraboloid. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Find the normal vector :

rewrite as Level surface  : $$F(x,y,z)= x^2+4y^2+1-z$$

Normal vector at point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ :

$$\nabla F(x_0,y_0,z_0)= \frac{\partial F } {\partial x}~\hat{i} + \frac{\partial F } {\partial y}~\hat{j} + \frac{\partial F } {\partial z}~\hat{k}  $$

$$\nabla F(x_0, y_0, z_0)= 2x_0~\hat{i} + 8y_0~\hat{j} + -1 ~\hat{k} {\tag 1 }$$

Vector on the plane :

$$(x-x_0)~ \hat{i}+(y-y_0) \hat{j} + (z-z_0) \hat{k} \tag{2} $$

$\space $
Normal vector (1) perpendicular to $(2)$ so their dot product is zero :

$$2x_0 (x-x_0) + 8y_0(y-y_0) - 1 (z-z_0) =0 \tag{3} $$

Expanding :

$$ 2xx_0-2x_0^2 + 8yy_0- 8y_0^2- z +z_0 =0 \tag{4} $$

With replacing $z_0 = x_0^2+4y_0^2 +1$ :

$$2xx_0-x_0^2-4y_0^2+8y_0y-z+1 = 0 \tag{5} $$

Since the plane contains the origin $ (x,y,z)= (0,0,0)$

$$ 1 = x_0^2+4y_0^2 $$

$$1 = {z_0}- 1, ~ z_0= 2 $$

Comment: The equation $z = 2x^2 + 8y^2$ describes a paraboloid, not a plane.

Comment: @beertje00 yes made the changes